# Why does random keep selecting the same choice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a code that returns yes or no to the user, but the output is always yes.

What should I change or add to make the answer change?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

list=["yes", "no"] #a list of answers
answer=random.choice(list) #choosing an answer

root=Tk(className="yes or no") 

lab=ttk.Label(root, text="what's your question" ) 
lab.pack()

#ask user for input
U=ttk.Entry(root) 
U.pack()

def return_answer():
    U.get()
    U.delete(0, END)
    U.insert(0,answer)

B1=ttk.Button(root, text="ok",command=return_answer)
B1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You only make the random choice once, when are you *expecting* it to change?

Comment: when i ask another question the answer is still  yes

Comment: What do you mean *"when i ask another question"*? When you click the OK button? That **does not** make a new `random.choice`.

Comment: `answer` points to the return value of 1 call to `random.choice` in this case, it doesn't describe such a call.

Comment: okay, so i should make a function that make a new random choice every time ok button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

Delete

```
answer=random.choice(list) #choosing an answer
```

and replace

```
    U.insert(0,answer)
```

with

```
    U.insert(0, random.choice(list))
```